# Integer literals in any base in C++?

Tags: c++, radix

In C++, it is possible to assign ints in decimal: `int x = 158`, in octal: `int x = 0236` and in hexadecimal: `int x = 0x9e`. What are the simplest ways of defining `int`s in any base, e.g. binary, base 3, base 9, whatever? Are there standard prefixes like `b101110`, or is the process more convoluted?

Thanks.

Comment: I think if you want to define `ìnt` with another base than the usual you have to write a specific function for that (or create a new data type...)

Comment: Binary literals with the `0b` prefix were added to the standard in C++14.

Comment: As @Michael said, there's `0b` in C++14; other than that, all you will *ever* need (unless you are a total madman) is decimal and hexadecimal (and *maybe* octal if you are dealing with UNIX permissions).

Comment: @Michael Which isn't widely available yet, and doesn't address his question (e.g. base 3, base 9, etc.).  (And binary literals without some sort of separator character are largely unusable.)

Comment: @Griwes Actually, octal is very widely used.  Given the syntax, you can't express 0 in decimal, it must be `"0"` (octal) or `"0x0"` (decimal).

Comment: Would `0x0` not represent zero in hexadecimal? I was under the impression that `00` would represent 0 in octal.

Comment: @Johan A literal starting with `0` (not following an `x` or `b`) is an octal literal, so technically `0` is octal; but seriously, why would you care? The result is the same...

Comment: Ehm, what is wrong with this question? (Hint: absolutely nothing)

Comment: @leemes I suppose you're right. Since zero is zero in any base, it makes no difference how you write it.

Comment: @Johan Ah I misread your comment. You're discussing the `0x0` version. Yes it is hexadecimal, not decimal.

Comment: @JamesKanze: it really doesn't matter. I'd say it's that way to avoid complexity during lexing. The fact `0` is octal means pretty much nothing; if we didn't have octal literals, `0` would be decimal, which is my point - except of when you are dealing with UNIX permissions, octal literals are not useful.

Comment: @Griwes They can be useful in all scenarios in which every set of three bits builds up some kind of "unit" (like UNIX permissions do, but there are other cases). What's missing are quadral literals (or how would you call base 4?) so we have all powers-of-two.

Comment: @leemes I know of no such scenario that's actually common except UNIX permissions.

Comment: @Johan A typo.  `"0x0"` is clearly hexadecimal; as I said in the preceding sentence, you can't represent 0 in decimal.

Comment: @Griwes: The literal `0` is an octal literal, so you use octal literals quite a lot.

Comment: @Griwes As the language is defined, octal constants are widely used for 0.  There are other uses as well: on 36 bit systems with 9 bit bytes, I would imagine that they are more frequent than hexadecimal, and at least two systems use base 8 in their floating point representation.  (In the past, they were widespread in the PDP-11 world, because the machine instructions broke down into 3 bit groups.  This influence probably explains why C originally only had octal, and not hex, and why the Unix file modes break down into groups of three bits.)

Comment: Sure I use octal literals, but that's by accident, because someone some time ago decided to use `0ooooooo...` for octal literals. Doesn't change what I said; stop being a smartass, @JamesKanze. Show me a 36-bit system, because I am not sure if there's any single one that is relevant to any discussion about a general use language.

Comment: @Griwes You obviously didn't understand my comment in the sense it was made.  (There was some irony meant.)  And while 36 bit machines aren't common on desktops, there are still 36 bit mainframes being manufactured (and they have a C++ compiler).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binary literals (`0b01010110101`) have been added in C++14.

Other bases aren't supported, but they can be emulated using the templated raw form of user-defined literals and constexpr. Andrzej Krzemienski describes it here: https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2012/10/23/user-defined-literals-part-ii/

Answer (score 2):

First: your example doesn't assign, but initializes.  Second, you assign an expression to an `int` (or you initialize it with an expression).  And finally, integral literals (which are only legal in an expression) can only be expressed in decimal, octal or hexadecimal; the C family of languages doesn't support anything else.

Comment: Slightly wrong; there's `0b` in C++ now (and it's been supported for quite some time via extensions).

Comment: @Griwes True.  I haven't been active in the standards committee since C++11 was adopted, so I'm not always up to date.  I see that they also allow a separator character in it; it would be practically useless otherwise.  (IIRC, g++ has supported it for a very long time.  But, again IIRC, g++ allowed `$` in it (and in some other places as well).)